# Make Swift JSONDecoder not fail when type on key not match

Tags: json, swift, decoder, jsondecoder

I have one simple struct like that:

```
struct Object: Codable {
    let year: Int?
    …
}
```

It's fine when decode JSON like `{ "year": 10, … }` or no `year` in JSON.
But will fail decode when JSON has different type on key: `{ "year": "maybe string value" }`

How could I not fail decode process when type not match on the Optional  property?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implement `init(from:)` in `struct Object`. Create `enum CodingKeys` and add the `cases` for all the `properties` you want to parse.

In `init(from:)` parse the `keys` manually and check if `year` from `JSON` can be decoded as an `Int`. If yes, assign it to the `Object's` `year` property otherwise don't.

```
struct Object: Codable {
    var year: Int?

    enum CodingKeys: String,CodingKey {
        case year
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        if let yr = try? values.decodeIfPresent(Int.self, forKey: .year) {
            year = yr
        }
    }
}
```

Parse the *JSON* response like,

```
do {
    let object = try JSONDecoder().decode(Object.self, from: data)
    print(object)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

**Example:**

1. If *JSON* is `{ "year": "10"}`, *`object`* is: `Object(year: nil)`
2. If *JSON* is `{ "year": 10}`, `object` is: `Object(year: Optional(10))`

Comment: Could I custom the JSONDecoder to make that happen but not custom the Codable struct? That's pain to implement all things like that.

Comment: Yes it it. Its better you prefer changing the API response to return consistent types for the keys.

Comment: There is no other way to handle that. You cannot customize the JSONDecoder for this kind of implementation.

Comment: I use Scripting Bridge to communicate with other Mac app via Apple Event. So I can not change the response. In face I should assert all the response from other side will change in some times. But little change should be OK. That's is user expect.

Comment: Thank your reply. I hope Apple will improve the decoder to make more custom options for us.